# From where does Authenticate.php get its constructor parameter?

Tags: php

This might be obvious to php developers. I am new to php, so please help.
When reading Laravel code the "src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php" file, I noticed this piece of code:

```
public function __construct(Auth $auth)
{
    $this->auth = $auth;
}
```

If I php works similar to other OO languages, `$auth` should be injected from somewhere. I could not find where it is from in the code base.

Comment: This is called [dependency injection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/container)

Comment: Why not set a breakpoint such that your debugger stops there? Or use `debug_backtrace` to show such details without a proper debugger?

Comment: I have tried to set a breakpoint. It does not stop there.

Comment: Are you sure this class is instantiated anywhere?